# Analysis of a MOSFET circuit using node method

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to learn SCS model for mosfets and I have two questions.

First, when a mosfet is not in saturation and it is turned on, it behaves like a variable resistor and its resistance changes depending on the gate to source voltage. From this, I draw the image below but I am not sure if it is correct. Is it correct ?

[image]

Second, how can I analyze the same circuit when the mosfet is in saturation using node method.

[image]

I thinks it is (Vout / RL) - ids = 0

where ids = K(Vgs - VT)^2 / 2

But again, I am not sure about this and I think it is incorrect.

(This is my first post in this website so if I made any mistakes I am sorry.)

Comment: What makes you think that your solutions are **not** correct? Have you compared the results to a simulation or an actual circuit.

Comment: I checked the second question in proteus. I used 24V for Vs, 5V for Vgs, 1k resistor for RL and 10K variable resistor connected to Vgs to change the mosfet input and mosfet was N channel VN121. For every 0.05 change in Vgs, voltage across RL also changed 0.05 all the time. This is why I think my second equation is not correct because if it was correct, results would change in a more quadratic way when Vgs changed. I am really confused at this point.

Comment: Vout is the voltage across RL and the current through RL is ids and it is not linear so when ids changes with respect to Vgs, the voltage should also change in a non-linear way right ?